# The following data would have been submitted to the server (in Laravel 8)

Tags: html, datatable, routes, modal-dialog, title

I try using modal on this page but I encountered an error saying

> 127.0.0.1:8080 says The following data would have been submitted to the server

[image: 1]

Answer (score 4):

Fixed

I am able to fix this by locating this file `"js/pages/data-table.js"` and I comment out the `"Form inputs"`

```
//---------------Form inputs
// var table = $('#example6').DataTable();
//    $('button').click( function() {
//        var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
//        alert(
//            "The following data would have been submitted to the server: \n\n"+
//            data.substr( 0, 120 )+'...'
//        );
//        return false;
//    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason commenting the form input did not work out. All you have to do is copy the entire code in the Js/pages/data-table.jd into another JS file. Include the new js file into your project
Remember to comment out or remove the form input example6 data table in your new js file.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Check your route that
Route::post('/store', [UserController::class, 'UserStore'])->name('users.store');

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).